Periodic maps whose set of periods is an additive subgroup
Let $G$ be a subgroup of the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ such that $G≠\{0\}$ and $G≠ \mathbb{R}.$
$(1)$ Prove that there exists at least one non-constant periodic map whose set of periods is precisely the set $G$.
$(2)$Find all maps that satisfy the property mentioned in $(1)$.
For $(1)$ It suffices to consider $f(x) = χG(x)$. Then $G$ will be equal to $wℤ$ for some $w > 0$ ( since the maps are non-constants).
Is there any way on how to find all the functions satisfying the property in $(1)$.

Partition $\mathbb{R}$ into cosets: $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}x+G$, where the sets $x+G$ are defined as $\{y\in \mathbb{R}:y-x\in G\}$. The periodicity implies precisely that function $f$ must have the same value on each coset: $y_1\in y_2+G \implies f(y_1)=f(y_2)$. We can pick the value of $f$ on each coset independently (with axiom of choice? I don't know too much about that). Pick any function $F: \{x+G:x\in \mathbb{R}\}\to \mathbb{R}$ that maps every coset to a real number. Then these $F$ defines exactly the functions $f$ whose periods contain $G$ by taking $f(x)=F(x+G)$.
Now we still need to check that there are no other periods (thanks @Adayah for pointing this out). We claim that $f$ has no periods $g'\notin G$ if and only if $F$ is `non-periodic' (where $F$ being periodic means there is $p\notin G$ such that $F(G+x)=F(G+x+p)$ for all cosets $G+x$):

If $f$ has a period $p\notin G$ then $F(G+x)=f(x)=f(x+p)=F(G+x+p)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
If $F$ has a period $p\notin G$ then $f(x)=F(G+x)=F(G+x+p)=f(x+p)$.


This is wrong - one of the functions defined this way is the zero function which doesn't satisfy the condition that the set of periods is precisely $G$.

Indeed, I edited the answer

For any $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have that:

The set of periods of $f$ contains $G$ if and only if $f$ factors as $\mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{R}/G \xrightarrow{F} \mathbb{R}$ for some $F$, where $\pi$ is the quotient map.

Given a function $f$ satisfying the above, its set of periods will be precisely $G$ if and only if $F$ has no non-trivial period as a function $\mathbb{R}/G \to \mathbb{R}$ (the notion of a periodic function makes sense when the domain is an arbitrary group, especially abelian). Unfortunately, there seems to be no easy way to explicitly construct all such functions.
